# Stopping a loop with onclicklisteners with a button

Tags: android

I created a thread, with a while and a for loop in it. The while loop is watching the stop variable (default false), which will become true when the loop stopping button is pressed. The for loop is should have to fill the squad_0 Byte[] (length of 4), and if the i is bigger than the squad_0, then set the i to 0, so the user can fill it again, until it presses the stopping button.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (stop) {
                //the program stops there
                for(int i = 0; i > squad_0.length; i++){
                    squad_0[i] = set_sqm0();
                    if(i++>squad_0.length)
                        i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    //without the while it run everything above
```

I fill the array with this code:

```
public Byte set_sqm0() {
    selected = 0;

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selected = 0;
        }
    });
    //It's the same for b-f


    return selected;
}
```

It should check what the user pressed. In the program I defined it from a to f, and set a as 0 and, b as 1, f as 5 and so on. The ending button have this code:

```
public void endt(View view){
    stop = true;
}
```

The program stop before the while(stop). If I delete the while loop, the program run until the end, without waiting for any button press or anything.
 Can anybody help me what is the problem with this code? I just simply don't get it why it isn't working.

Comment: `The program stop before the while(stop)` wha tdoes it mean? Does the app crash?

Comment: No, it stops there and do nothing.

Comment: because stop is false initially. It should be `true` so the while loop can run and `false` when you have to stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, your problem is at the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i > squad_0.length; i++)
{
    squad_0[i] = set_sqm0();
    if(i++>squad_0.length)
        i = 0;
}
```

The loop won't run since `i` is always smaller then squad_0.length (i=0,squad_0.length = 4), so you should change the sign from > to <.
And even after that, the loop is an infinite loop, since `i` never get to be greater or equals to `squad_0.length`. 
You should remove the `if` statement inside the loop, so the `while` loop statement will be checked each time the for loop ends and only then, it will start the for loop again.

Moreover, your `while` statment should be `while(!stop)` instead of `while(stop)` in order to run in the first time since you set `stop=false` as default, and you set `stop=true` when you want to quit the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I think now it works, because now it crashes with this: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException (Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views). I will check that tomorrow.

Comment: Great to hear that! Could you please set my answer as correct?